# Wordpress add parameters with friendly url structure

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I build a Wordpress website with a page called 'Nieuwsberichten'.
The url looks like

https://www.example.com/nieuwsberichten

This page is dynamic and I need an extra parameter called 'news_page'

https://www.example.com/nieuwsberichten/?news_page=recent

The URL above is not friendly so I create a rewrite rule for this and I add the variable 'news_page'.

**functions.php**

```
function add_query_vars($vars){   
    $vars[] = 'news_page';     
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars', 10, 1 );

function rewrite_paged(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^nieuwsberichten/([0-9]+)/?', 'nieuwsberichten?news_page=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_paged');
```

After this I flushed the permalinks
menu -> settings -> permalinks -> save

If I browse to

https://www.example.com/nieuwsberichten/recent/

It will redirect to

https://www.example.com/nieuwsberichten/

What do I miss in my code?

Hope somebody can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

In the regex part, you specify an entry for numbers only, but you pass text like recent in your url. Maybe the error is here. Please check if it works with number input, edit your expression if that's the problem. Also, the url structure you specified does not seem to be quite correct.

Anyway, I'm not sure of my answer so I'd appreciate it if you could confirm after checking.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/
This may be the function you should use for the parameters you add. This function will also not require the query_var function. So I think you won't need to use the other function.

I'm not in a position to check or test right now. If your problem is not solved, I will look into it in detail.

You can use it like this:

```
function rewrite_paged(){
        add_rewrite_tag('%news_page%', '([^/]+)');
        add_rewrite_rule('^nieuwsberichten/?([^/]*)$', 'nieuwsberichten?news_page=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_paged');
```

Also if you are pointing to a page you will need to use page id or pagename. A blog or a product etc. If it is, there will still be parameters you need to use and you should redirect this url to index.php. I'm leaving an example for you to understand what I'm saying, and for your review, you can take a look at the rewrites on your site as follows:

Review examples:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
print_r($wp_rewrite);
```

Examples:

Match Pagename:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nieuwsberichten/?([^/]*)$', 'index.php?pagename=nieuwsberichten&news_page=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Match Page ID:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nieuwsberichten/?([^/]*)$', 'index.php?page_id=10000&news_page=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

If you have an installation outside of wordpress your example is correct but if it will be inside wordpress all requests should be directed to index.php. Therefore, you may need to edit the code I have given like these examples.